# Hang during pool.join() asynchronously processing a queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

On the python docs, it says that if maxsize is less than or equal to zero, the Queue size is infinite. I've also tried `maxsize=-1`. However this isn't the case and the program will hang. So as a work-around I created multiple `Queues` to work with. But this will not be ideal as I will need to work with even bigger lists and then would have to subsequently create more and more `Queue()` and add additional code to process the elements.

```
queue = Queue(maxsize=0)
queue2 = Queue(maxsize=0)
queue3 = Queue(maxsize=0)
PROCESS_COUNT = 6

def filter(aBigList):

    list_chunks = list(chunks(aBigList, PROCESS_COUNT))

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=PROCESS_COUNT)

    for chunk in list_chunks:
        pool.apply_async(func1, (chunk,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    allFiltered = []

    # list of dicts
    while not queue.empty():
        allFiltered.append(queue.get())

    while not queue2.empty():
        allFiltered.append(queue2.get())

    while not queue3.empty():
        allFiltered.append(queue3.get())

    //do work with allFiltered

def func1(subList):

    SUBLIST_SPLIT = 3

    theChunks = list(chunks(subList, SUBLIST_SPLIT))

    for i in theChunks[0]:

        dictQ = updateDict(i)
        queue.put(dictQ)

    for x in theChunks[1]:

        dictQ = updateDict(x)
        queue2.put(dictQ)

    for y in theChunks[2]:

        dictQ = updateDict(y)
        queue3.put(dictQ)
```

Comment: What is the error message? Nothing is infinite, and if you push too many items on the list you will end up without memory.

Comment: No error message no crashes. Just hangs. But good point. I will be pushing up to 6000 items onto the `Queue`. Currently I am doing about 300 between these 3 Queues. So it wouldn't be pleasant to be doing about 20 new Queues in the future.

Comment: How large is each item in bytes (approx.)?

Comment: I printed the size of each dictionary item using `sys.getsizeof()` which returns: 664. The dictionary holds 6 float values and 1 string value.

Comment: It hangs on `put()` or `get()`?

Comment: I added a print statement right after `pool.join()` but it didn't get printed so it hangs up on/before that. However the program runs through the entire `aBigList` because I added print statements into the function call `updateDict()`. So I would say it hangs up at `put()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue happens because you do not process the `Queue` before the join call.
When you are using a `multiprocessing.Queue`, you should empty it before trying to join the feeder process. The `Process` wait for all the object put in the `Queue` to be flushed before terminating. I don't know why it is the case even for `Queue` with large size but it might be linked to the fact that the underlying `os.pipe` object do not have a size large enough.
So putting your `get` call before the `pool.join` should solve your problem.

```
PROCESS_COUNT = 6

def filter(aBigList):
    list_chunks = list(chunks(aBigList, PROCESS_COUNT))
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=PROCESS_COUNT)
    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    async_result = []
    for chunk in list_chunks:
        async_result.append(pool.apply_async(
                            func1, (chunk, result_queue)))

    done = 0
    while done < 3:
         res = queue.get()
         if res == None:
             done += 1
         else:
             all_filtered.append(res)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # do work with allFiltered

def func1(sub_list, result_queue):
    # mapping function
    results = []
    for i in sub_list:
        result_queue.append(updateDict(i))

    result_queue.append(None)
```

One question is why do you need to handle the communication by yourself? you could just let the `Pool` manage that for you if you re factor:

```
PROCESS_COUNT = 6

def filter(aBigList):
    list_chunks = list(chunks(aBigList, PROCESS_COUNT))
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=PROCESS_COUNT)
    async_result = []
    for chunk in list_chunks:
        async_result.append(pool.apply_async(func1, (chunk,)))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Reduce the result
    allFiltered = [res.get() for res in async_result]

    # do work with allFiltered

def func1(sub_list):
    # mapping function
    results = []
    for i in sub_list:
        results.append(updateDict(i))
    return results
```

This permits to avoid this kind of bug.

**EDIT**
Finally, you can even reduce your code even further by using the `Pool.map` function, which even handle chunksize.
If your chunks gets too big, you might get error in the pickling process of the results (as stated in your comment). You can thus reduce adapt the size of the chink using `map`:

```
PROCESS_COUNT = 6

def filter(aBigList):
    # Run in parallel a internal function of mp.Pool which run
    # UpdateDict on chunk of 100 item in aBigList and return them.
    # The map function takes care of the chunking, dispatching and
    # collect the items in the right order.
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=PROCESS_COUNT) as pool:
        allFiltered = pool.map(updateDict, aBigList, chunksize=100)

    # do work with allFiltered
```

Comment: Finally got around to running my program using your answer! It runs perfectly fine with around 300 items, but for about 2000 items, it crashes at `allFiltered = [res.get() for res in async_result]` saying: `multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError`. I am using your 're-factor' suggestion code. Also to answer your question: I didn't know of `apply_async` and all that. Still new to multiprocessing in python.

Comment: `MaybeEncodingError` happens when the worker fails to pickle the results. It might be that the returned results are either too big, or non picklelisable. You should try to run sequentially your 6 calls and pickle the results to make sure you so not have an issue in the objects you return, as the pickling/unpickling error are lost in the pool internal mechanism. To reduce the size of the chunks, see my edit for lower chunk size and more compact code.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've been messing around with the amount of chunks and PROCESS_COUNT to see if I can find a "sweet" spot now that I have a better understanding of this stuff, but no luck. I tried using your `pool.map` code and had to change it a bit due to an `AttributeError`: from `with.....` to `pool = multiprocessing.Pool.......`. After I got it to run, I still come across the `MaybeEncodingError`.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? The last code in the answer works fine on python3.6. For the `MaybeEncodingError`, this is due to an error while pickling the result. So it should come from the result of your function `updateDict` which is not described. Try running `res = map(updateDict, aBigList); [pickle.dumps(r) for r in res]` to see if you get a better error to help you debug your code.

Comment: I am running Python 2.7.13. Hm, would you be ok continuing this in a chatroom if you want? I don't want to flood this thread and will come back here if we find a solution to this.

Comment: Fixed! The above code works fantastic. The `MaybeEncodingError` happens inside `updateDict`. The refractoring really helped make the code look and function much better.